# Erro MySQL 1064

Tags: mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

no insert abaixo recebo o seguinte erro.

```
INSERT INTO dump1090 ('hex','squawk','flight','lat','lon','validposition','altitude','vert_rate','track','validtrack','speed','messages','seen') VALUES ('e4827e','3670','TAM3754 ','-22.850818','-43.070628','1','10350','3328','8','1','219','162','161')
```

> 1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a ''hex','squawk','flight','lat','lon','validposition','altitude','vert_rate','trac' na linha 1*

Comment: Tire as aspas dos nomes das colunas. Assim: INSERT INTO dump1090 (hex,squawk.... , mas mantenha nos valores.

Answer (score 3):

Você não deve utilizar aspas para informar o nomes da colunas, apenas para informar os valores não numéricos.

Seu insert deve ficar assim:

```
INSERT INTO dump1090 (hex,squawk,flight,lat,lon,validposition,altitude,
   vert_rate,track,validtrack,speed,messages,seen) 
VALUES ('e4827e',3670,'TAM3754 ',-22.850818,-43.070628,1,10350,3328,8,1,219,162,161)
```

De fato, os valores numéricos podem vir entre aspas ou não que o banco trata isso, mas os valores alfanuméricos devem estar entre aspas obrigatoriamente.

Comment: OMG nao acredito 20 anos de programacao e nao percebi essa cagada kkk obrigado !